# Azure mobile services - multiple azure active directories

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-active-directory, azure-acs

We want to develop a mobile application which will be used by users in multiple organizations. Each of these organizations will have an Azure Active Directory tenant owned by them. We want to use Azure Mobile Services for authenticating users.

Once the user is authenticated and the mobile app has the JWT token, it will be subsequently sent to our API gateway to access various services.

Is is possible to use Azure mobile service Identity component in such a way that the app can authenticate against multiple Active Directory tenants? In other words can we create a multi-tenant mobile app which can authenticate against multiple Azure Active Directory tenants owned by different organizations?

Azure Active Directory does support development of [multi-tenant web apps](https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-MultiTenant-OpenIdConnect-DotNet) and there are sample applications available which demonstrates this capability. However is it possible to achieve the same functionality in a mobile app using Azure mobile services?

Answer (score 1):

It is very much possible to build multi-tenant mobile apps backed by Azure Active Directory authentication. However, I doubt if Mobile Service will help here. Rather, I'll recommend creating a WebAPI project with AD authentication and consume those APIs in mobile apps. The samples that you've mentioned can be very much useful.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I checked Azure Mobile services and it supports authentication via various identity providers(Google, Twitter, LiveID, Azure AD etc...). Isn't it possible to authenticate via these services, get the JWT token and then pass the token to Web API?

Comment: It is possible to use 3rd party identity providers. But you'll need to write your own token handler.

Comment: Could you provide an explanation or reference to how you would create your own third-party identity provider? This info is surprisingly hard to find for the new Mobile App Services sdk.